# Big-O notation for a function $f(x)$ that tends $\infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ at an arbitrarily small rate?

Tags: limits, order-theory, computational-complexity

Is there are a big-O notation for a function $f(x)$ that tends $\infty$ at an arbitrarily small rate?

Obviously, the expression $\mathcal{O(1)}<f(x)<\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{\log(x)})$ is not good enough (I just randomly choose $\sqrt{\log(x)}$. What is a smart expression that I can replace $\sqrt{\log(x)}$ with?

Comment: For any growth rate there is a smaller growth rate.

Comment: Is $f(x) = \omega(1)$ not what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the notation $f(x)=\omega(1)$.

The notation $f = \omega(g)$, $f$ dominate $g$, is defined as
$$\forall k > 0 \, \exists n_0 \, \forall n > n_0 \colon |f(n)| > k\cdot g(n)$$
or
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left|f(n)\right|}{g(n)} = \infty$$

Comment: Doesn't this just say that $f(x)\to\infty$? OP seems to ask how to say that a function tends to infinity at a smaller rate than the rate at which any other function tends to infinity, which is not possible.

Comment: I think $f(x) = \omega(1)$ means that $f(x) \rightarrow \infty$ at an arbitrary/any rate, which includes 'arbitrarily small rate' which is somewhat poorly defined in my question. If understood correctly, $f(x) = \omega(1)$ serves my purpose.

Comment: I see, then I have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a good way to do this with big-$O$ notation. No matter what expression you put into it, you can take a logarithm or a square root to find a significantly smaller function that still goes to infinity.

But there are other (albeit less common) notations for similar notions. In your case, you want $$f(x)\in \omega(1)$$This says that $f$ dominates $1$. Which is to say, for any multiple of $1$, $f$ is eventually bigger.